# iOS - SiriKit Intent Extension - Cannot see prints nor hit breakpoints

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit

I'm trying to incorporate SiriKit intents into my application. I followed all the instructions including

- Enable SiriKit
- Add the usage string in Info.plist
- Add the intent extension target to the project
- Add the intent I want to support in the Info.plist of that new target
- Add my handler method for the intent
- Add the SiriKit authentication request in the AppDelegate

When I open Siri now and I ask the required question for the intent it does ask me if I want to open my app, so I go ahead and click yes and my app is opened. However, no print-statement in my intent handling method nor a breakpoint in there is hit.

I also tried starting the intent extension scheme via the run button in Xcode, I select my app on the popped up drop down, but then nothing on the phone appears and it just says Finished running my app on the device, no print statement or breakpoints hit either.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you got solution?